# azure data lake - validate require fields in csv

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm getting started with Big Data. Assuming I will receive multiple csv files which will be stored on Azure Data Lake and they have a defined schema, what will be the best way to:

-validate if the required field will be provided in the CSV (not all fields are required)

-get the records that successfully match the defined schema

-get the records that don't match the defined schema

I've took a look on USQL and how fast it can merge / extract / group data, but it doen't seen to be right tool to validate row by row. I also took a look on Azure Data Factory, but I'm not sure if's the right tool or how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Data factory is more focus on data transferring. When transfer the CSV file, we need to do the schema mapping between Source and Sink, it also provides us the way to modify/manual mapping  the schema.  But that's no real validate the schema. I don't think Data Factory is the right tool  for you.